# Why Doesn't This Bit of Code Work Without My Hack?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a situation where I'm making an API call to a Laravel back-end and eager-loading some data.  The data is a collection of locations, each of the form:

```
location = {
    id: ..
    name: ...
    ...
    docks: [
        {
            id: ...
            name: ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The end result of this epic should be to dispatch 2 actions, one with a list of the locations, and another with the list of all the associated docks

Taking it from the response to the api call, the following throws a Typescript error and won't compile:

```
.mergeMap(({ response }) => {
  if (response.messages) {
    return Observable.of(GetLocationsForReceiverFailedAction(response.messages))
  }
  const locations = response.locations.map((locn: any) => ({
    id: locn.id,
    receiver_id: locn.receiver_id,
    name: locn.name,
    address: locn.address,
    city: locn.city,
    state: locn.state,
    zip: locn.zip
  }))
  const location$ = Observable.of(GetLocationsForReceiverSuccessAction(locations))
  const docks: any[] = []
  response.locations.forEach((locn: any) => {
    locn.docks.forEach((dk: any) => {
      docks.push(dk)
    })
  })
  const docks$ = Observable.of(GetDocksForReceiverSuccessAction(docks))
  return Observable.merge(location$, docks$)
})
.catch(() =>
  Observable.of(
    GetLocationsForReceiverFailedAction([
      'Something went wrong trying to reach the server'
    ])
  )
)
```

The error reads: 
"Argument of type '({ response }: AjaxResponse) => Observable<{ type: ActionTypes; messages: string[]; }> | Observab...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: AjaxResponse, index: number) => ObservableInput<{ type: ActionTypes; messages: string[]; }>'."

If, however, I change the line:

```
return Observable.merge(location$, docks$)
```

to:

```
return Observable.merge(location$, Observable.empty(), docks$)
```

(ie, separating by 2 observables by an empty observable in the merge (or concat, which works the same way here), it compiles and runs.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: The error is about AjaxResponse, I assume from `Observable.ajax` usage? But I don't see it being used or any ajax in the provided code?

Comment: I didn't include that part.  See below

Comment: headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      return ajax({
        url: getLocationsAndDocksForReceiverURL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        responseType: 'json',
        body: { receiver_id, token },
        crossDomain: true
      })